# How to make `getfacl` run with certain order?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, acl, chmod, chown

I use `getfacl -RP ../www > permission_backup` to store the permission and `Beyond Compare` to compare two `permission_backup`,if permission has any change,I will run `setfacl --restore`.

I found a problem,I run `getfacl -RP ../www > permission_backup` to the same folder twice,items in `permission_backup` may have different order,then `Beyond Compare` will tell me there's big different.

For example:
One `permission_backup` is as below:

```
# file: ../www/info/2013-09-05/16.html
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--

# file: ../www/info/2013-09-05/1.html
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--

# file: ../www/info/2013-09-05/23.html
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

Another one is:

```
# file: ../www/info/2013-09-05/23.html
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--

# file: ../www/info/2013-09-05/16.html
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--

# file: ../www/info/2013-09-05/1.html
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

How to   make `getfacl` run with certain order?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the directory manually, using a loop or `find` call and then call `getfacl` on each file.