# How to backup and restore permission with certain order and can be compared to find the difference?

Tags: bash, shell, permissions

I want to find a solution to backup,restore,compare permissions.

At first, I can use `getfacl` and `setfacl`,but output of this method is not ordered.[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61193088/how-to-make-getfacl-run-with-certain-order)
Then, I tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3450585/7936836),but output is one line string,hard to compare to find the difference.

Is there any solution to backup/restore,and compare folders and files permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anything can be improved,such as add `print0`,pls comment or create a new answer.

```
find * -depth -exec stat --format '%a %U %G %n' {} + > ../repo/all_folders_files_permission

while read PERMS OWNER GROUP FILE
do
    chmod "$PERMS" "$FILE"
    chown "${OWNER}:${GROUP}" "$FILE"
done < ../repo/all_folders_files_permission
```